# "self-signed certificate in certificate chain" while attempting to install an extension via command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate

My aim is to install multiple vscode extensions at once in a windows machine programmatically.

I developed a batch file to install these extensions.
When trying to install any vscode extension from cmd using the following command:
`code --install-extension <extension-identifier>`

I am facing the following issue:
[image]

- I am able to install extensions using the same above command after disabling **Proxy Strict SSL** (File->preferences->settings) setting in vscode GUI.
- To disable it programmatically I need to edit **settings.json** file and set `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false`.
- Extension installation is failing on few machines even after Disabling Proxy Strict SSL in vscode gui is and editing settings.json through batch file is getting very complex.

Is there any alternative clean way to install vscode extensions programmatically, is there a better mechanism than batch script?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_legacy-proxy-server-support